# Can a military satellite be used to spy on any place on Earth undetected?

Tags: military, reconnaissance-satellite

Of course like many people I only know about military satellites from movies, so I wanted to get some information (perhaps get some myths debunked) by some experts:

1. Can the military use a military satellite to spy on any place on Earth ? live?
2. If a military satellite is used to spy on a rival country, can the latter detect it?
3. I also was told that Google Maps sometimes blurs military bases, which made me wanna ask, is there some technology which can protect a military zone from prying satellites by shielding the area or something?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Try to limit each question to one question, not 3

Comment: "can the latter detect it ?" That depends a lot on which country you are asking about.

Comment: 1. yes, 2. yes, because the satellite itself is quite easy to detect. 3. camouflage, fake targets, or just hide underground when the satellite flies by.

Comment: AFIAK the standard approach in Area 51 was everything interesting was under cover whenever a Russian bird was above the horizon.  At one point the local paper published some Russian spy sat photos--buildings and runways, not a bit of equipment to be seen.

Comment: @OrganicMarble i meant in terms of technology

Comment: Please, ask one question per question.

Comment: 3. Yes, it's called a roof.

Comment: @Topcode, Jörg: it seems to me that it would be ridiculous to split this into three separate questions, given that they are so closely related to each other. Can either of you explain how this would improve the quality of the site?

Comment: In particular, Google have now removed the blurring they applied to Russian military facilities, since they no longer want to afford them that protection.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> Can the military use a military satellite to spy on any place on Earth?

Yes, but only in the absence of clouds.  The highest resolution imagery is only available during the day.  I strongly suspect they have infrared imagers as well for nighttime imagery, but those inherently have a lower resolution.

In principle, radar or even passive microwave could be used to look through clouds, but the resolution for passive microwave would be much poorer still.

> Live?

No.  The highest-resolution imagers are in low Earth orbit, so they would have to wait for a satellite to pass.  They would also need to programme the imager on where to look, as it cannot look in all directions at the same time / quickly enough to cover everything during a pass (except at much lower resolution, but there are open data satellites such as weather satellites doing that already).

> If a military satellite is used to spy on a rival country, can the latter detect it?

They can detect the satellite, but they wouldn't know if it was looking in their direction, nor if it was taking a photo.

If the spy sat uses radar, it would be easy to detect.

> is there some technology which can protect a military zone from prying satellites by shielding the area or something

Yes.  The technology is called *digging*.  By hiding things underground, they cannot be seen from space or from the air.  Other technologies may be camouflage or deception.

Comment: Yes i understand the point you made about having to wait for a satellite to pass the right place, and having them to program it for a specific spot, but at that point in time, wouldnt that allow them to view that location live for a while ? (at least until the satellite is out of range of view)

Comment: @RedZ Yes, in theory it could take multiple photos during an overpass, or even video, with some limitations.

Comment: @redZ. The orbital speed of LEO satellites means the time period it can view a single location from low earth orbit is very short, a couple of minutes at most. To get a rough idea  find a time when you can spot the ISS https://spotthestation.nasa.gov/tracking_map.cfm and time how long it is visible to you (possible viewing) and within 30 degrees of vertical (optimal seeing for a camera). Also relevant that most of the places you might want 'live' feed of are not where your ground stations are so true live feed only easy to do over your own territory.

Comment: @GremlinWranger makes sense, thank you for the information

Comment: Regarding "*In principle, radar or even passive microwave could be used to look through clouds, but the resolution would be much poorer still.*", check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic-aperture_radar, which can provide very good resolution. Scott Manley gives a nice intro here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2bUKEi9It4. Obviously this is not passive, i.e., does not answer the original question.

Comment: One limitation as to which places on earth are observable is that the place must be within range of one of the satellites. The orbits are of course chosen to maximize exposure of interesting locales. Satellites can be moved to different orbits, but that is expensive in terms of fuel, and takes time. And some areas may be very hard to reach no matter what - usually, the polar regions are among them, unless some of the satellites have circumpolar orbits.

Comment: @KevinKeane which is why the US DoD is heavily investing in things like the Boeing X-37 at the moment - reusable (meaning it doesnt have to have tech which is designed to last decades), repositionable and uses techniques that can save on fuel for repositioning (uses less fuel to dip back into the atmosphere, reposition using the atmosphere, then boost slightly back to a higher orbit).  A very nice platform if you can get it...

Comment: @Simon I'm aware SAR exists, but I have no clue about its use for surveillance.

Comment: @Moo Most Earth observation satellites are in sun-synchronous polar orbits and can observe any place on Earth at least twice a day (at least once during daytime, potentially at a large angle)

Comment: @gerrit yes, but they are very trackable and predictable, while the X-37 can be dramatically retasked and the cost is just ending its mission early due to fuel exhaustion, vs shortening the life of a non-refuellable multi-billion dollar spy sat…

Comment: @Moo On the other hand, if I see a spy sat flying over, it's just in its regular orbit, and it's nothing special.  If a spy _plane_ flies over, then it's much more likely they're specifically targeting me.

Comment: @gerrit the X-37 isnt a spy plane, its in orbit, its another satellite - just one you can never be sure is where it was when you last looked.  It just dips into the atmosphere to get an assist on orbital changes with its wings (apparently).  So you would have to be watching the orbit of *everything* up there all the time to see any specific interest in you.

Comment: @Moo The point with satellites is that their positions are easy to predict once you know their orbital parameters. They also rarely change those if they don't have to and there are a bunch of well funded organizations interested in tracking those with great precision, if only to avoid crashing their own stuff into them. So assuming you have the ability to detect objects up there, finding the one that doesn't belong is actually quite trivial.

Comment: About deception, it's been heavily used during WWII to feed false intel to reconnaissance aircrafts, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Bodyguard

Answer (score 17):

With respect to item 3, blurring photos - yes this happens.

It does not however happen through cloaking technology but rather more boringly by various organizations requesting it of either the company taking the original images or of Google etc who is hosting them. [Random list](https://traveltriangle.com/blog/hidden-places-on-google-earth/).

One thing to be aware of here is that for most of the urban areas you see in google maps or similar services the images or not actually from satellite but an aircraft. Generally currently (2022) if you can see which way cars are facing it is an aircraft image, nor from space. Since these aircraft are normally operating with permission and under jurisdiction of the local government so much easier for them to mandate blurring or manipulation of the resulting images.

For google street view you can even request your own [blurring](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7011973?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop). In all such measures it is worth remembering that blurring [attracts attention](https://fas.org/blogs/security/2018/12/widespread-blurring-of-satellite-images-reveals-secret-facilities/) which may be counter productive.

Comment: You made some really good points, i didnt know that google maps uses aircraft images though, is there any other (free) service which provides satellite imagery though ? because the other day i tried to check a very remote location in an ocean but everything was low quality and low res so i guessed it might have been just computer generated and a not a real satellite feed, what do you think ?

Comment: @RedZ There's not much call for high-quality photos of the surface of the ocean, which is neither distinctive nor consistent, so while I'm sure the photos are genuine I'm equally sure that they are the lowest priority for getting better quality photos.

Comment: @RedZ If you are viewing Google Maps, the image watermark contains the year the image was taken and the bottom of the screen tells you the company that provided it, which changes dynamically at different scales.

Comment: Commercial satellite imagery can spot cars, tell which direction they're facing, and let you distinguish classes of vehicle (eg. compact car vs. pickup truck) with reasonable accuracy.  Military satellite imagery can distinguish model of car with reasonable accuracy.  To compare, [a parking lot as seen by one of Maxar's satellites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy53D.png), and [that same parking lot as seen by a simulated KH-11 satellite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv9Tv.png).

Comment: That list in your first link seems to be largely nonsense, but it's easy to find such areas in France: go to Paris and look for the darker patches, somewhere inside them there'll be a blurred out building for pretty obvious reason (prison, military facilities)

Answer (score 8):

One surprising aspect of satellite imagery is that sometimes you can "see" things that are not there!

In regions of strong sunlight vehicles and aircraft on the ground leave cool shadows which remain for a time after the craft is moved. Thermal imaging can capture this. Also... engine runup and heat plume on ground can show which craft are on alert status, even at night.

During testing of aircraft and missiles for stealth capabilities they (or mockups) are mounted on a tall post and RF energy is directed at them. Our researchers had to make sure the craft were 'posted' for very short periods, day or night, so thermal shadows were minimized.

Comment: That is very interesting, i did not know that, im trying to search more about this (thermal shadows) but couldnt find much, would you have any example image about it ?

Comment: I don't understand how this answers _any_ of OPs questions.

Comment: @pipe  this information went to this point. Someone trying to hide stuff before a satellite comes over may fail if satellite uses sufficient IR imaging.   This goes to the "undetected" by the hiders part of OP.

Answer (score 8):

To answer question number 2.

There's actually a cottage industry among civilians to document and track spy satellites.

Here is a link with some more information about one such organization: [Meet the Amateur Astronomers Hunting for Spy Satellites](https://www.supercluster.com/editorial/meet-the-amateur-astronomers-hunting-for-spy-satellites)

You don't commonly hear about it in movies, but spy satellites tend to be quite large and to have large power requirements in order to support their advanced capabilities. This can result in them having expansive arrays of solar panels which reflect light at predictable angles. Satellites also often travel predictable paths in order to spy on certain regions.

Literally anyone with a sufficiently advanced telescope, or a good head for math, can scan the sky looking for satellites orbital paths, and for the reflections in their solar panels. It's become exponentially easier with the increased availability of AI that can comb hours of video footage looking for transiting objects or flashes from solar panels.

There was a big commotion around 2002-2004 (I don't remember exactly when) after astronomers in Japan noticed a previously undocumented satellite with solar panels the length of a football pitch, in exactly the right orbit to observe North Korea. The size of the solar array marked this out as being a particularly energy hungry spy satellite. Probably one with multiple passive and active system on board rather than just optics.

If civilians can do this, then the military of most nations can do it too.

Comment: Very interesting information, im gonna research more based on what you mentioned, thank you very much!